# paintComponent does not work on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

so I have a Board class that extends JPanel and method write that when called saves some coordinates and calls repaint. However, the effect of repaint is not displayed on screen. When I tried to add JLabel with redbackground to the panel it showed up, so the panel is showing, it's just that repaint does not work.

```
public int x, y;
public JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private int xx,yy;
private Color c;

public Board(int x, int y, int wolfNumber, int hareNumber){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

    wolvesCoords = new int[wolfNumber][2];
    haresCoords = new int[hareNumber][2];
    setLayout(new GridLayout());

    add(panel);
}

public synchronized void write(int xx, int yy, Color c){
        this.xx = xx;
        this.yy = yy;
        this.c = c;

        repaint();
}

@Override 
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int width=panel.getWidth()/x;
        int height=panel.getHeight()/y;


        g.setColor(c);

        g.drawRect(xx*width, yy*height, width, height);
        g.fillRect(xx*width, yy*height, width, height);
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: Board class that extends JPanel

Comment: What you want to achieve? why `panel` is used here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 3):

Call `super.paintComponent` first

One of the jobs of `paintComponet` us to fill the `Graphics` context with the components background color, this is done to ensure what ever was painted to the a `Graphics` context before is "cleaned" off

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)for more details

Comment: 1+ It appears that he thinks that he'll save time by not reading the Swing Graphics tutorials. Little does he know that the opposite is true.

Comment: Well there is no difference at all, I tried it already. Also @HovercraftFullOfEels - No, it won't, or atleast not now. I am not native english speaker and understanding even a short tutorial would take me weeks. For example, I have no idea what he talks about in the second senteces and I would have to google a lot to just understand this one thing.

Comment: @user3369008 Its possible that the panel is covering the contents of this component, but since you've decided not to provided a runnable example that demonstrates your problem, we're jus making guesses now

Comment: @user3369008 Based on your question and example code provide from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620780/board-isnt-repainting-properly?noredirect=1#comment36266009_23620780), you don't seem to understand how painting works in Swing.  Painting is destructive, that is, each time `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to repaint the entire state the component, not just what you want to update...

Answer (score 1):

Override `paintComponent` for instance member `panel` rather then Board `JPanel` class itself.

```
panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...// your code here
    }
};
```

---

Why `Board` class is extending `JPanel`?

Try to use design pattern such as **Favor Composition over Inheritance**

Comment: Well yes indeed it does, but even if I set them manually to anything it still doesn't matter - no changes. I already fixed that too.

Comment: It would have worked too but I just removed the panel and it was K aswell. However, do you know if there is a possibility to not lose everything on screen everytime repaint() is called? By repainting I just want to color one rectangle on screen, without losing all the others.

Comment: Have a look at [how to use clip to reduce paint time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139461/how-to-use-clip-to-reduce-paint-time).

Comment: Uhm, I don't know how can that help me.

Comment: Read more about **Swing clipping**. A clip is a region of whole window. You can just update a section.

Comment: First read and search on Google. Make some programs if there is any doubt then ask a separate question on **StackOverflow**.